# How does the ChatGPT API timeout parameter works in stream mode?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using the OpenAI library with `timeout` and `stream=True` parameters. I want the timeout to happen on a token base, meaning that the timeout will happen and raise an exception if any token request takes more than the timeout value in seconds to respond.

Does the timeout behavior with stream mode work like that? Or should I implement my own timeout functionality? I couldn't find a specific answer detailing whether the timeout is checked for each token request or the entire completion request.